# How do you find the triple integral?

Tags: integration

I need some help finding the triple integral of: 1/xyz. All three integration limits are from 1 to e^2. Help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Thanks! And I managed to pull out 1/yz since it'll be a constant; and I integrated 1/x. But I got stuck after that.

Comment: Oh! I think I found my mistake, I accidentally did the derivative instead of the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_1^{e^2} \int_1^{e^2} \left(\int_1^{e^2} \frac 1 x\cdot\underbrace{\frac 1 y \cdot \frac 1 z} \, dx\right)\,dy\,dz
$$
The part over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ does not change as $x$ goes from $1$ to $e^2$; and it is a *factor*, i.e. the thing being integrated is the part over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ *multiplied by* something.  Hence that part can be pulled out:
$$
\int_1^{e^2} \int_1^{e^2} \left(\underbrace{\frac 1 y \cdot \frac 1 z}\int_1^{e^2} \frac 1 x \, dx\right)\,dy\,dz
$$
Doing this innermorst integral, you get a number, $2$.

Then iterate as needed.

Comment: I tried the problem, and I double checked my integrals, but I keep getting the wrong answer. :( I keep getting 8 instead of the answer in my book which is 6. Integrating x gave me: 2/yz dydz, then integrating y gave me: 4/z dz and evaluating that gave me 8.

Comment: The answer in your book is wrong.  It should be $8$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_1^{e^2}\frac{dx}x=2$.  Then you're integrating $\displaystyle\int_1^{e^2} \frac1y\cdot\frac1z\cdot2\,dy$ and you get $\displaystyle\frac2z\cdot2 = \frac4z$. Finally, you're integrating $\displaystyle\int_1^{e^2}\frac4z\,dz$ and you get $8$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know, that when integrating or derivating multivariables, the variable that you ARE NOT operating counts as a constant, so:

$$ \int_1^{e^2}\int_1^{e^2}\int_1^{e^2}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{z} \,dx\,dy\,dz = \int_1^{e^2}\int_1^{e^2} \frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{z} \left(\int_1^{e^2}\frac{1}{x}\,dx \right )\,dy\,dz = \int_1^{e^2}\int_1^{e^2} \frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{z} \Big[ \ln(x) \Big]_1^{e^2} \, dy\, dz $$

$$ \Big[ \ln(x) \Big]_1^{e^2} = \ln(1) -\ln(e^2) = 0 - 2\ln(e) = 2 $$

$$ = 2\int_1^{e^2} \frac{1}{z} \left( \int_1^{e^2} \frac{1}{y}\,dy \right )\, dz = (\cdots) $$

I hope I have helped, 
Saclyr.